# Detecting incomplete PNG's and JPEG's

Tags: image, png, jpeg, detection

I've inherited a number of jpeg's and png's, some of which are incomplete. How can I detect the incomplete ones programmatically? Is it possible?

I'm not looking for a specific language implementation, just a generic idea to then implement.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be perfect in terms of reading the file's header, comparing the expected data size with the actual, etc., I'd just try to open it in a library or application (imagemagick comes to mind) or convert it to a different format, and see what it does with the incomplete ones.

Comment: For PNGs, you only have to read chunks and skip them immediately. The last one should be a complete `IEND` chunk.

Comment: @Jongware - that's useful to know! Thanks, that's allowed me to find all the incomplete pngs. Any idea about jpegs?

Comment: I've attempted to use the same method for looking for an end byte at the end of JPEG's. From what I can read this isn't always the case, but it's good enough for me!

Comment: For PNG, I'd use pngcheck, which can be downloaded from http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html

Comment: For JPEG, it depends upon what you mean by incomplete? If the file is truncated, you would just need to look for the EOI marker at the end. If the data is incomplete, you'd need to decompress and look for errors.